# Help regarding adding multiple locations to plugin Google Maps

Tags: xmap

I implemented the [Google Maps plugin by Reumer Tech](http://www.mapsplugin.com/Google-Maps/Documentation-of-plugin-Googlemap/parameters-of-plugin-google-maps.html) on my client's [website](http://www.wilddusk.com/contacts).

I need help regarding how to add multiple locations (main office, branch office) to the map.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `kml` parameter to have multiple markers.

Example map with [KML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) file:

```
{mosmap kml='http://your.joomla.com/media/markers.kml'}
```

There is online KML generator [here](http://www.mapmash.in/kmlpoint.html). Just create KML and save it to your Joomla! site. Then edit `{mosmap}` code.

Comment: Unable to figure out how to edit {mosmap} code. Generated code:                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
 <Document> I understand if there are two locations, I need to create such code twice. Where do I place that code?
  <name>KML </name>
  <description>KML Description</description>
  <Placemark>
   <name>WildDusk</name>
   <description>Chandannagar</description>
   <Point>
    <coordinates>88.3589, 22.8828</coordinates>
   </Point>
  </Placemark>
 </Document>
</kml>

Comment: This code has to be in article or custome HTML module. Find it and then edit.

Answer (score 0):

As Rene points out, multiple markers with the Google Maps plugin by Mike Reumer is only possible using KML files.

It may be easier to find and install a different extension that displays multiple markers such as [GMapFP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/maps-a-weather/maps-a-locations/gmapfp-google-map) or [Maps2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/maps2) or similar.