# Google maps Joomla 3.x.x

Tags: joomla-3.x

I was tasked to edit an article in Joomla which embed a Google maps plugin.I want to show two specific users below

[image]

during mouse hover like this

[google maps](http://lawrencetractor.com/Departments/Sales/Sales-Rep-Map.aspx)

Any idea on this? I already embed the Google maps plugin using this short code

```
 <p>{mosmap labeltext='H'| zoom='15'| overview='2'| text='</p>
 <div style="width: 200px;">Home</div>
 <p>'| marker='0'}</p>
```

But I have no idea how to achieve like the one in the link above

Comment: Welcome to JSE :) As Mirko Mikan pointed out, it would help if you specified which plugin you were using. Please be mindful that in the case of 3rd party extensions it is best to ask the developers first. Other than that, good question. I hope you find a good answer :)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/10572/120

Answer (score 2):

By the syntax `{mosmap}` used in articles, it seems that the plugin you used on that site is [Google Maps by Reumer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/google-maps-by-reumer), which is crucial to answering your question.

That is very well written extension with numerous options (literally hundreds of them) and **it is quite impossible to give you exact answer unless someone actually tested all of them**.

Luckily, plugin is also very well documented on the following links: [Plugin Home page](http://www.mapsplugin.com/Google-Maps/Documentation-of-plugin-Googlemap/welcome.html) and [Documentation of plugin Googlemap](http://www.mapsplugin.com/Google-Maps/Documentation-of-plugin-Googlemap/), and you should focus on finding and testing options used for `marker` and `text` parameters used in article, and configured in plugin's admin options.

Answer (score 2):

To display multiple markers using the Google Maps plugin by Mike Reumer you will need to learn about KML files.

It is probably easier to find and install a different extension that makes it simple to display multiple markers on a map such as [GMapFP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/maps-a-weather/maps-a-locations/gmapfp-google-map) or [Maps2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/maps2) or similar.